# Delphi 2007 + PNG drop-shadowed shape + W10 = black frame

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-2007

I created a PNG image with photoshop: a simple shape with a drop shadow. Then I put it in a TImage under Delphi 2007 (dependency: PNG library called "PngComponents"). Execution on Windows XP produces *almost* the expected result (background is Delphi IDE):
[image: splashscreen on XP]

But on Windows 10 there's a black frame instead of the shadow:
[image]
Not tested on W7/W8 but I guess that I could get the same problem. Here is the dfm content:

```
object frmSplashScreen: TfrmSplashScreen
    Left = 517
    Top = 321
    AlphaBlendValue = 0
    AutoSize = True
    BorderStyle = bsNone
    ClientHeight = 392
    ClientWidth = 528
    Color = clBtnFace
    TransparentColorValue = clBtnFace
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -11
    Font.Name = 'Default'
    Font.Style = []
    FormStyle = fsStayOnTop
    KeyPreview = True
    OldCreateOrder = False
    Position = poScreenCenter
    OnClose = FormClose
    OnCreate = FormCreate
    PixelsPerInch = 96
    TextHeight = 13
    object imgLogo: TImage
        Left = 0
        Top = 0
        Width = 528
        Height = 392
        AutoSize = True
        Picture.Data = {44A(...)E426082}
        Transparent = True
    end
end
```

What's wrong with my image and/or settings?

---

I said that result on XP was almost the one expected: indeed if I change the background of the form (ie minimize the window under the splashscreen), well the transparent part of the image isn't refreshed:
[image]

Comment: In Windows Vista the graphic subsystem was significantly changed. Maybe your version of "PngComponents" is too old? I have no factual info though, that this would/could be the case.

Comment: Actually PngComponents is not directly involved here. It is just that before Delphi 2009 came with PNG support out of the box, PngComponents used to add the original PNG units from Gustavo Daud. IIIRC, there was a problem with those original files under Vista and newer. This probably works with recent Delphi versions.

Comment: Ok I get it. So I really need to migrate my legacy apps to Berlin version. Thanks.